# Rotate middle flex column effect

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I hope you can help me with this effect. I was trying, but I could not achieve it :(.

I want to make this positioning effect [image]

I am using flex but when I try to grow the green div, the other two are shrinking Despite I set `flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 1;` in the diagonals class to override in green div the flex like `flex: 0 0 1.5` for example

I still getting blank spaces like this

[image]

Here my HTML

```
<div class="full-height">
        <div class="diagonals">
            <div class="diagonal">
            </div>
            <div class="diagonal">
            </div>
            <div class="diagonal">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <img class="logo-image" src="{{asset('/landingImages/logo_landing.jpg')}}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my scss

```
.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: black;
}

.diagonals {
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


.diagonal {
  height: 120%;
  background: greenyellow;
  flex:1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-position: center;
  &:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url("/landingImages/gym.jpg")
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(15deg) translateY(-8%) translateX(0%);
    background-image: url("/landingImages/gym3.jpg")
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url("/landingImages/cycling-landing.jpg")
  }
  span.diagonal-text {
    text-shadow: 5px 1px #636b6f;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;  
    left: 30%;                      
    top: 40%;                   
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me what I am doing wrong. **Thanks in advance !**

Answer (score 1):

An isolated solution works with pseudo elements (`:before` or `:after`). This way you have clearer control of the rotated background relative to the content which remains unrotated.

Just make sure the rotated pseudo element is big enough to cover the area so the illusion is complete. Adjust the `scale` value in the transform and the `height` of that element to hide the rotated corners.

```css
.my-flex-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden; /* required to prevent overflow and scrollbars */
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.the-one-that-rotates {
  position: relative;
  background: yellowgreen;
  max-width: 300px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.the-one-that-rotates:after {
  content: ''; /* pseudo element needs content property even if empty */
  position: absolute;
  background: yellowgreen; /* same background treatment (color or image) as .the-one-that-rotates */
  height: 130%; /* adjust this value to need */
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.65); /* adjust these values to need */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}
.stuff-inside {
  position: relative; /* position relative here is so that we can apply z-index to make sure the content is above the rotated background */
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.unique-bkg {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/500);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.another-unique-bkg {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/550);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-flex-wrapper">
  <div class="flex-item unique-bkg">
    <!-- the blue side -->
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item the-one-that-rotates">
    <div class="stuff-inside">
      <h2>Some stuff</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut fringilla eros porta, ornare elit sit amet, finibus felis. Integer condimentum, nisl elementum pellentesque euismod, tellus turpis varius magna, a congue odio magna et magna. Phasellus posuere ipsum quis lectus faucibus blandit. In eu lacinia tellus, id suscipit tellus. Duis ac enim viverra ligula hendrerit varius nec eget dui. Nulla sit amet accumsan leo. Suspendisse eget erat posuere, imperdiet erat quis, tincidunt velit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item another-unique-bkg">
    <!-- the red side -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At first, looks well but iIdon't use colors. I use images and the background you set as green won't work because if I change the green width the diagonals do not keep as diagonal. I want the middle column keep over the another two without the flex shrink or grow them. But I dont know how do that behaviour

Comment: The colors are just to show you can have different background... updating showing you how to use image there too. This method does what you want, there is no shrink the content column remains at the `max-width` you set. Run the code snippet above and click the Full page link to see.

Comment: Read the comments in the CSS they point out which values need to be updated to suit the exact size you want. If you adjust the `height` and the transform `scale` values accordingly you should be fine.

Comment: @MarcoFeregrino glad I could help! Would you consider this answer accepted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190177/discussion-between-simran-and-marco-feregrino).